# How to indicate whether to send a cross site cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, samesite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4boz.png)

Pls how do I solve the same site issues

Comment: Instead of linking the screenshot of your code, please add the code and describe the problem in here

Answer (score 0):

We have a few options to manage the cookies from the server side. Like the **SameSite** attribute which lets servers specify whether/when cookies are sent with cross-site requests.

To specify that cookies are sent on **both originating and cross-site** requests, but only in secure contexts (i.e. if `SameSite=None` then the `Secure` attribute must also be set).

```
Set-Cookie: mykey=myvalue; SameSite= None
```

To Specify **only** sent to the site where it **originated**.

```
Set-Cookie: mykey=myvalue; SameSite=Strict
```

Cookies are sent by the browser to the server when an HTTP request starts, and they are sent back from the server, which can edit their content. Cookies are essentially used to store unique details to **identify the user's session**. Refer to the **MDN documentation** about Cookies for more details.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies